# Dynamic class bindings in Vue.js/TypeScript

Tags: typescript, class, vue.js, dynamic

I want to use dynamic class bindings to update an icon in an error message based on the input typed by a user into the input field.

Basically, I have a password input field and below it a little error message stating "Minimum 10 characters" with a cross icon. I want it that when the length of the password is over 10 characters that the icon updates from a cross/times to a check. Currently it displays the cross/times icon but it does not switch when password.length > 10

```
<input :type="type" v-model="password" />
<p>
 <span :class="`fa fa-${showIcon}`"></span>
 Minimum 10 characters
<p>
```

My computed property:

```
get showIcon(): string {
 return this.password.length >= 10 ? "check" : "times"
}
```

I expected it to work so I am not entirely certain what is going wrong here. Any advice on what I may be doing wrong? Thanks in advance!